# Extremely confused about using classes in different projects/referencing packages visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio, nuget

I have been trying to use a few classes I created for a console app a while ago in a asp.net web application I am creating. The first thing I tried was to just copy over the classes from the console app project and then import the nuget packages so the classes would compile. However, the SAME NuGet packages that allow those classes to function perfectly for the console app are not working when I download them for the web app. Basically, whenever I declare an instance of a class that should have been imported with the NuGet packages, I get the error:

```
The type 'Microsoft.Search.Autopilot.IConfiguration' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Search.Autopilot, Version=10.8.13.52429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=471e7408fd06c98f'.
```

As an example, lets say I have a class called SampleClass which declares instances of classes from certain NuGet packages. The following will compile fine:

```
using blablapackage.blabla


namespace WebSite1
{
    public class SampleClass
    {


    public void random(ForeignClassFromPackage x)
    {
          //do some stuff

    }
}
```

However, the following will throw the error I mentioned earlier:

```
using blablapackage.blabla


namespace WebSite1
{
    public class SampleClass
    {
         ForeignClassFromPackage y = new ForeignClassFromPackage(); //this is the origin of the error

    public void random(ForeignClassFromPackage x)
    {
          //do some stuff

    }
}
```

Doing this exact same thing in the console app that I made earlier works completely fine. I don't understand why it is throwing this error for the webapp.

Comment: You imported, but did you actually add the reference?

Comment: Yes, I right clicked the project and clicked manage nuget packages, installed the packages, then wrote the "using" line at the top of the class.

Comment: But in your references folder, is it there and "valid looking"? Thats different than installing the package (trust me, they don't always match)

Comment: Well there is no references folder. It placed a bunch of .dll and .pdb files in the Bin folder. In the console app there is a references folder which contains references. This is an asp.net website btw. Should I recreate the project as a web application project? There is a reference folder for web app projects.

Comment: So, you have web site project, not web application, is this correct? @SKLAK

Comment: Yes, I just recreated it as a web application and imported the references. This worked, however now I have a new problem. The web app opens in a browser but throws this error: "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Search.Autopilot' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. "

Comment: Ok. This is easy. First, don't use Web Site - this is crap. Second, right now you have issue that you build your app for AnyCPU? x64? x86? But the `Microsoft.Search.Autopilot` is not matching. Just to be sure, run development console `corflags path\Microsoft.Search.Autopilot.dll` and see what architecture it has.

Comment: I'm not sure, how would I check this?

Comment: Yes, I mean how would I run development console? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: Go to programs menu, to .net, run .net cmd as admin and run the command. Results are like this http://jimiz.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/corflags.png. Or here is another option. In your project properties, create configurations for all 3-x64, x86, AnyCPU(probably default) and build using each. When succeed - this is good

Comment: Ok, I got the following results: http://i.imgur.com/vdYrNvd.png

Comment: I can give you answer why original Web Site didn't work. I think!!! it is because even though you had your packages, you still need to create `*.refresh` file for each dll and point it to package folder

Comment: Oh, no!! where `path` you need to give full path to your dll. ha-ha

Comment: FYI: I just retried that command with the right path instead of "Path" and still the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55100/discussion-between-sklak-and-t-s).